# Filter Data by Seasonal Ranges Over Several Years Based on Month and Day Column in R Studio

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter a large dataset to contain results between a range of days and months over several years to evaluate seasonal objectives. My season is defined from 15 March through 15 September. I can't figure out how to filter the days so that they are only applied to March and September and not the other months within the range. My dataframe is very large and contains proprietary  information, but I think the most important information is that the dates are describes by columns: SampleDate (date formatted as %y%m%d), day (numeric), and month (numeric).

I have tried filtering using multiple conditions like so:

```
S1 <- S1 %>%
  filter((S1$month >= 3 & S1$day >=15) , (S1$month<=9 & S1$day<=15 ))
```

I also attempted to set ranges using between for every year that I have data with no luck:

```
 S1 %>% filter(between(SampleDate, as.Date("2010-03-15"), as.Date("2010-09-15") & 
                as.Date("2011-03-15"), as.Date("2011-09-15")&
               as.Date("2012-03-15"), as.Date("2012-09-15")&
               as.Date("2013-03-15"), as.Date("2013-09-15")&
               as.Date("2014-03-15"), as.Date("2014-09-15")&
               as.Date("2015-03-15"), as.Date("2015-09-15")&
               as.Date("2016-03-15"), as.Date("2016-09-15")&
               as.Date("2017-03-15"), as.Date("2017-09-15")&
               as.Date("2018-03-15"), as.Date("2018-09-15")))
```

I am pretty new to R and can't find any solution online. I know there must be a somewhat simple way to do this! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/11570343)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)

# convert a date like this '2020-01-01' into this '01-01'
df[,`:=`(month_day = str_sub(date, 6, 10))]
df[month_day >= '03-15' & month_day <= '09-15']
```

Comment: I get an error saying month_day not found when I try this.

Comment: maybe include library(stringr)

Comment: I ended up doing this and it seems to work! 
S1 <-S1 %>%
  filter(SampleDate >= as.Date(paste(year(SampleDate), 03, 15, sep = "-")),
         SampleDate <= as.Date(paste(year(SampleDate), 09, 15, sep = "-")))